# basename and extension stripped

Tags: regex, bash

I want to get the basename of a variable, which is always going to be a file with an extension, with the extension stripped and set it as a variable.

For example, if $foo is /$HOME/Desktop/doc.txt, then I want the variable $mediaid to be "doc"

`mediaid=$(basename $foo | cut -d. -f1)` works

but

`mediaid="$(${foo##*/} | cut -d. -f1)"` does not

I'm getting my quotes/braces/$ messed up but I'm not sure where or how exactly.

Also, is there a more, um, elegant way to write this that avoids piping it to `cut` ?

Comment: Do you know the extension?

Comment: Please show example strings and desired results.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ok. I added those in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an expansion that removes patterns :

```
basename="${foo##*/}"
basename_stripped="${basename%.*}"
```

The `%` causes removal of the shortest match, starting from the end of the value of `foo`, of the following pattern.  `.*` is a globbing pattern, and matches a literal period followed by anything.

The `##` causes removal of the longest match of the following pattern, starting from the beginning, and `*/` matches everything up to the last path separator.

An expansion is performed by the shell, with no external command or subshell, so it will be much quicker.

Comment: yes, but that only removes the extension and doesn't help with also getting the basename of the file, which I need.

Comment: Cool. Is there a way to combine that so I don't need to set two different variables?

Comment: @Bleakley  You cannot combine them, but you can reuse the same variable in the second assignment : `basename="${basename%.*}"`

Comment: @Bleakley  By the way, this will likely be orders of magnitudes quicker than a command substitution with two external commands executed.

Comment: You are the boss. <°))))))))))))))>